# Diferença entre Get e Post AJAX

Tags: javascript, ajax

No AJAX, tenho as funções `$.post` e `$.get`.

Sempre usei o `$.post`, e nunca tive problemas.

- Mas qual a diferença entre eles?
- Em quais situações eu deveria usar cada um?

Eu procurei aqui no SO uma pergunta sobre isso, pois estava na dúvida, mas não achei

Comment: @LucasCosta A pergunta que você indicou fala sobre sobre os métodos HTTP, esta fala sobre o uso desses métodos com Ajax.

Comment: @Renan Você tem razão, mas lá na outra resposta tem as informações que eu buscava, obrigado mesmo assim!

Comment: Considerei como duplicada @Renan porquê os métodos são diferentes justamente devidos a diferença entre os métodos HTTP, que está bem detalhada na resposta Victor.